# Invariant direct image of skyscraper sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of smooth projective complex curves such that $f$ is a cyclic cover of degree $r$. So there is an action of the cyclic group $G=\mathbb{Z}_r$ on $X$ and quotienting out by the action gives $Y$.

Suppose that we have a skyscraper sheaf $S$ supported at finally many points of $X$. Consider the invariant direct image $(f_*S)^G$? Is this always zero? Or does this depend on the support of $S$? It would be helpful if someone provides some examples.

Comment: I think it depends on the support. If you take a skyscraper supported on the fiber over a point $x$, which is just $r$ points, the invariant direct image should be a skyscraper at $x$.

Comment: More generally, the invariant direct image is an equivalence of categories between $G$-equivariant sheaves on $X$ and sheaves on $Y$, so if you just start with a sheaf on $Y$ and take pullback, the invariant pushforward will be non-empty.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand this a bit more. Suppose we have a double cover that is $r=2$. If $S$ is supported at two points not in the same fibre. Then what is the invariant direct image? Can we say?

Comment: The invariant direct image makes sense only if the sheaf $S$ is $G$-equivariant (otherwise $f_*S$ has no $G$-action). In particular, the question about $S$ being supported at two points in different fibers doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user52991 if I may add to Sasha's answer and clarify on my previous one, you can basically get anything as the invariant direct image. Start with your favorite sheaf on $Y$, and take the pullback. Then the invariant direct image will be the sheaf you started with.

Comment: (at least that is what I think, and I think the sufficient and necessary condition is that the $G$-action is free, which is true in your case)